# xamarin 'System.Object' is not defined or imported

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

[image: Screen shot of error+code]

I just installed xamarin since I'm trying to learn c# and make use of xamarin as well.

I'm getting the "xamarin 'System.Object' is not defined or imported" error.

Any one have any tips? I'm assuming something might be missing or maybe my xamarin is located somewhere it shouldn't be? it's currently in `c:\program files(x86)\xamarin studio`.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please include code and output as text in your question instead of linking to a screenshot. like this nobody can find this question. 

have you tried cleaning and rebuilding? what IDE are you using? xamarin studio? try visual studio (for mac). community edition is free

Comment: I have a windows computer and yes this is xamarin studio. Are you suggesting I use Visual Studio instead? Will I still be able to code/learn in C#? Also, does Visual Studio have the same functionality as Xamarin Studio?

Comment: visual studio has a few more functionalities. Yes you can still use and learn C#. just give it a try and maybe it helps with your problem. i suggest downloading VS 2017 community

Comment: Xamarin Studio has be deprecated for a while now, Visual Studio (For Windows or Mac) has replaced it

Answer (score 1):

Usually if you restart your Visual Studio the issue should go away.
You are trying to create a Console Application, and it seems that the nuget packages were not installed properly. So you can either got to Project->Restore Nuget Packages (on Mac) or restart the Program and it will do it automatically.

Another possible reason could be that you removed the References to "System" from the References folder. You can right click on references and add it back, along with other "System" libraries.

If all else fails, you could also create a new Console application, and it will be visible again. If that doesn't work, you might have to reinstall the application.

Answer (score 0):

You will also see this error if you create a project with Visual Studio 2019 and try to compile it later with Visual Studio 2017. The new project structure seems to create an error when older Visual Studio version are confronted with it